# Kotlin function parameter with receiver, called from Groovy

Tags: groovy, kotlin, kotlin-interop

Kotlin and Groovy both provide a way to write a high-order function where the function parameter has an implicit receiver.

**Kotlin Version**

```
class KotlinReceiver { 
    fun hello() { 
        println("Hello from Kotlin") 
    } 
}

class KotlinVersion {
    fun withReceiver(fn: KotlinReceiver.() -> Unit) {
        KotlinReceiver().fn() 
    } 
}

// And then I can call...
val foo = KotlinVersion()
foo.withReceiver { hello() }
```

**Groovy Version**

```
class GroovyReceiver { 
    void hello() { 
        println("Hello from Groovy") 
    } 
}

class GroovyVersion {
    void withReceiver(Closure fn) {
        fn.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        fn.delegate = new GroovyReceiver()
        fn.run()
    }
}

// And then I can call...
def foo = new GroovyVersion()
foo.withReceiver { hello() }
```

My goal is to write the `withReceiver` function in Kotlin, but call it from groovy and have `{ hello() }` work. As written, though, Kotlin generates bytecode like

```
public final void withReceiver(@NotNull Function1 fn) { /* ... */ }
```

which Groovy treats as a function with a parameter. In other words, to call Kotlin's `withReceiver` from Groovy, I have to do this:

```
(new KotlinVersion()).withReceiver { it -> it.hello() }
```

In order to allow `{ hello() }` with no `it -> it.`, I have to add an overload that takes a `groovy.lang.Closure` as its parameter.

**Kotlin Version**

```
import groovy.lang.Closure

class KotlinVersion { 
    fun withReceiver(fn: KotlinReceiver.() -> Unit) {
         KotlinReceiver().fn()
    }

    fun withReceiver(fn: Closure<Any>) = withReceiver {
        fn.delegate = this
        fn.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
        fn.run()
    }
}
```

With that overload in place, given a `KotlinVersion` instance called `foo` the following line works in both languages:

```
// If this line appears in Groovy code, it calls the Closure overload.
// If it's in Kotlin, it calls the KotlinReceiver.() -> Unit overload.
foo.withReceiver { hello() }
```

I'm trying to keep that syntax, but avoid having to write that extra boilerplate overload for each high-order function my Kotlin library defines. Is there a better (more seamless/automatic) way of making Kotlin's function-with-receiver syntax usable from Groovy so I don't have to manually add a boilerplate overload to each of my Kotlin functions?

The complete code and compile instructions for my toy example above are [on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/drmoose/so-how-can-i-call-with-receiver-from-groovy).

Comment: where is the limit? why you can't create kotlin code that in byte code will look like this: `public final void withKotlinReceiver(groovy.lang.Closure fn) { /* ... */ }` ?

Comment: @daggett The Kotlin example in my workaround does exactly that, I'm just trying to avoid having to write a wrapper like that by hand for every high-order function in my library. I thought there might be some combination of Groovy magic and/or Kotlin compiler attributes that could achieve the same syntax without tons of hand-written boilerplate.

Comment: Please provide more details how do you see the groovy script/class and how it imports kotlin..

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, so I've edited the question to try to make it clearer what I'm trying to achieve. The context is that my Kotlin code is in a `buildSrc` folder, and I'm trying to make it callable from gradle scripts written in Groovy. I've checked the toy example, with compile instructions, [into gitlab](https://gitlab.com/drmoose/so-how-can-i-call-with-receiver-from-groovy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in groovy you can define new functions dynamically

```
KotlinVersion.metaClass.withReceiver = { Closure c-> 
    delegate.with(c) 
}
```

this will define new function `withReceiver` for class `KotlinVersion`

and will allow to use this syntax to `KotlinVersion` instance:

```
kv.withReceiver{ toString() }
```

in this case `toString()` will be called on `kv`

you can write the function that iterates through declared methods of your kotlin class with `kotlin.Function` parameter and declare new method but with `groovy.lang.Closure` parameter through metaClass.