# How to call Kotlin extension function from Groovy code?

Tags: kotlin, groovy, gradle-plugin, gradle-kotlin-dsl, extension-function

I am writing a Gradle plugin in Kotlin language using `kotlin-dsl` plugin:

```kotlin
plugins {
    `kotlin-dsl`
}
```

I have created a plugin class and an extension:

```kotlin
class MyPlugin : Plugin<Project> {

    private lateinit var extension: MyPluginExtension

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        extension = project.extensions.create("myPluginExtension")
        ...
    }

}
```

There is an infix function `foo` inside my extension class:

```kotlin
open class MyPluginExtension {

    infix fun String.foo(other: String) {
        ...
    }

}
```

Here is how plugin users are supposed to use my plugin (using Kotlin DSL):

```kotlin
plugins {
    id("my-plugin")
}

myPluginExtension {
    "first" foo "second"
}
```

I want to have the same syntax for plugin users that use Groovy language:

```
myPluginExtension {
    'first' foo 'second'   // cannot call Kotlin infix function using Groovy
    'first'.foo('second')  // this is not working too
    foo('first', 'second') // ok, but not desired syntax for me
}
```

I don't know Groovy much, but I've heard it has [extension methods](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_static_methods_2). How to make my plugin looks cool for Groovy lovers?

If it is not possible to make a function call directly, I believe there is a way to create a wrapper extension method in Groovy language that will call the Kotlin extension function.

I've found a similar question [Kotlin function parameter with receiver, called from Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51140120), but it is not exactly what I need.

Comment: It is possible to convert Kotlin extension functions to Groovy extension functions using a [module descriptor](http://groovy-lang.org/metaprogramming.html#module-descriptor), but Gradle does not support this https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/2973

Comment: still possible to register extension method from code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'm not familiar with kotlin, so, i'll be referencing java as a baseline

here is an extension method for `String` class in groovy world:

```
String.metaClass.foo = { x-> " foo( first:${delegate}, second:${x} ) "}


"aaa".foo "bbb"    //returns: foo( first:aaa, second:bbb )
```

in java you can use approximately this code to register extension method for some class:

```
class MethodFoo extends groovy.lang.Closure{
    public MethodFoo(Object owner){
        super(owner);
    }
    Object doCall(String second){
        return "foo( first:" + getDelegate() + ", second:" + second + " )";
    }
}

//-------------------------------
var mc = GroovySystem.getMetaClassRegistry().getMetaClass(String.class);
Class []argTypes = { String.class };
String methodName = "foo"
if( !mc.hasMetaMethod(methodName, argTypes) ){
    //instead of null it could be a reference to a gradle project if you want to access it inside a method with getOwner()
    mc.registerInstanceMethod(methodName, new MethodFoo(null));
}

//---- after this point in groovy you can make this call:
"aaa".foo "bbb"    //should return: foo( first:aaa, second:bbb )
```

---

PS: it's still possible to achieve syntax `"aaa" foo "bbb"`

groovy will translate this line to approximately following code:

```
plugin."aaa"( plugin.getProperty("foo") ).getProperty("bbb")

// where plugin."aaa" -> invoke method with name `"aaa"`
```

as soon as "aaa" is dynamic - you can implement [GroovyObect invokeMethod](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/GroovyObject.html) in your plugin that will be invoked on any unknown method call

this approach is quite tricky but doable.
i'm lazy to implement it in java. here is a groovy code that you can run in groovy console:

```
class MethodFoo{
    String first
    Object getProperty(String name){
        println( "foo( first: $first, second: $name )" )
    }
}

class Plugin{
    MethodFoo getFoo(){
        return new MethodFoo()
    }
    
    Object invokeMethod(String name, Object args){
        if(args.length==1 && args[0] instanceof MethodFoo){
            args[0].first = name
            return args[0]
        }
        throw new Exception("method not found: $name")
    }
}


new Plugin().with{
    "aaa" foo "bbb"    //prints: foo( first: aaa, second: bbb )
}
```

Comment: Do I understand right that you are registering a global extension function `foo` for all Strings? Is it possible to have a function `foo` that will work only inside `myPluginExtension {}` block?

Comment: correct. it's a registration of global extension function. the second approach is limited by scope